# Displays multiple lines in one graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have lists of points and there fit line model,
how I can combine them all into one graph?

This is the code that displays each one separately: 8 lines

```
Show[ListPlot@allbeeposition[[1, 1]],Plot[allLinesStraight[[1, 1]][x],{x,-10,10},PlotStyle->Red]]
```

.

.

.

```
Show[ListPlot@allbeeposition[[1, 8]],Plot[allLinesStraight[[1, 8]][x],{x,-10,10},PlotStyle->Red]]
```

Comment: does `Show[ListPlot[allbeeposition[[1]]], 
 Plot[Evaluate@Through[allLinesStraight[[1]][x]], {x, -10, 10}]]` give what you need?

Comment: For this case yes, but if I have more list numbers [X, Y] and let say Y = 80 but I want to display only the first 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 5X80 array of 2D lists each with length 20:

```
SeedRandom[1]
allbeeposition = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {5, 80, 20, 2}];

Dimensions[allbeeposition]
```

> ```
> {5, 80, 20, 2}
> ```

A 5X80 array of fit functions:

```
allLinesStraight = Map[Function[x, Evaluate@Fit[#, {1, x}, x]] &] /@ allbeeposition;

Dimensions[allLinesStraight]
```

> ```
> {5, 80}
> ```

Show plots of  row 1 and columns 1 thru 8 of `allbeeposition` and `allLinesStraight` in a single graph:

```
Show[ListPlot[allbeeposition[[1, ;; 8]]], 
 Plot[Evaluate @ Through[allLinesStraight[[1, ;; 8]][x]], {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]